# Problems Trying to showStatus Using identica-php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, statusnet, identica

I'm using the [identica-php](http://code.google.com/p/identica-php/) to get a single post using `showStatus`, just like this:

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include '../scripts/identica.lib.php';
    include '../misc.php';

    // your identi.ca username and password
    $username = $_GET['u'];
    $password = $_GET['p'];
    $userid = $_GET['uid'];
    $postid = $_GET['pid'];

    // initialize the identi.ca class
    $identica = new Identica($username, $password, "Terrarium");

    // fetch the timeline in xml format
    $xml = $identica->showStatus("xml", $postid);

    $identica_status = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $status = $identica_status->status;
    $user = $status->user;

    echo '<div id="singleStatus">' . $status->text . "</div><br />";
    echo '<div class="single_posted_at">' . $status->created_at . " via " . $status->source . '</div>';
    echo '<img src="' . $user->profile_image_url . '" class="identica_image">';
    echo '<a href="http://identi.ca/' . $user->screen_name . '" class="nameURL">' . $user->name . '</a>: ';
?>
```

But when I try to run the code everything I got is this:
[image: Result of the code]

What I'm doing wrong? An example of the XML result: http://pastebin.com/Q52yfQp9

*PS: I've tried to show just the XML to do a test and it worked, so it won't be a problem with the Post ID or the XML, but in the code*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

status is the root element of the XML, so it hasn't a getter in a SimpleXMLElement object.
Below your code revisited to work:

```
//$identica_status = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
//$status = $identica_status->status;
$status = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$user = $status->user;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't identica-php, it's how you're trying to use **SimpleXMLElement**. Your **$identica_status->user property** is not an array, it's an iterable and accessible object (according to [the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)).

try:

```
$user = $identica_status->user->children();
```

or it might be simpler to just access elements further down in the document tree like this:

```
$identica_status->user->screen_name
```

Comment: The first one returned this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /Users/Nathan/Sites/Terrarium/tabs/showpost.php on line 24` and the second one returned the same thing as shown in the question **:(**

Answer (score 0):

This library you're linking to is really, really old (sept '09) and StatusNet has evolved a lot since then. I'm not surprised this does not work anymore.

However, since Identica's API is similar to Twitter's, you could probably use a Twitter PHP library to do what you want.